# jQuery - counting elements with a function after page loaded

Tags: jquery

Ok, here is the setup for this example:

I have 50 results, so I run:

```
function divcount() {
 mycount =  $('div.item').length; 
}

divcount();
$('div#test').append(mycount);
```

To get the count of those results...and then display that count-fine.  The issue is the page uses AJAX calls to filter results and remove div.item's off the DOM.  For this example, it gets cut to 3 results.  After a mouseclick (click that activates the AJAX call) I want to count the results, 3, and display 3 results in #test...but it is using the original 50 and not 3.

I thought about putting:

```
function updatedivcount() {
 updatedcount =  $('div.item').length; 
}
```

into the mouseclick action, but that didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `.click()` event handler that fires the AJAX call?

Comment: can you show a code which is used to update count on click?

Comment: I thought it was .size() that you needed to use... not length. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: @ComputerArts: `size()` will return `this.length` with the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Should have read the whole description on the link I posted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the update code at the `success` callback of the `$.ajax()` call. Something like this:

```
$("#id_of_button").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function (data) {
      // Do something with the results...
      $('div#test').text($('div.item').length);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Except that there should be `text` instead of `append`

Comment: @FAngel: Hi, it depends on what OP wants to do, if he wants to replace  the existing value, or if he wants to keep adding the new ones. I simply used his original code, but it's easy to switch from one to the other.

Comment: I understand. But at the same time I suppose it is 99% that OP does not want to get 503 instead of 3. And next question may be "How can I get 3 instead of 50". Suppose it would be more correct to say "Except that there, possibly, should be `text` instead of `append`"

Comment: @FAngel: You're correct, I've updated my answer to reflect that and use `text()` instead.